# Is it ok to make an API call within a function in the model.py, why has my application slowed so much after doing it?

Tags: python, django, api, model, python-requests

I'm creating a crypto-currency app, I'm populating some tables with crypto data, in order to get some of this data I need to calculate api values against database values. I have done this by creating functions, and doing an api call in the models.py file, but it has slowed my application down so much. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way I could code this?

models.py below. Has slowed immensely since adding the 4 properties

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin = self.total_price / self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+self.currency + ', '+str(self.amount)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('transaction-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    @property
    def coin_value(self):
        try:
            current_price = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym="+self.currency+"&tsyms=EUR")
            price = json.loads(current_price.content)
            return price["EUR"]
        except:
            return 0


    @property
    def total_value(self):
        value = self.coin_value * self.amount
        return round(value, 2)

    @property
    def profit_loss(self):
        value = float(self.total_value) - float(self.total_price)
        return round(value, 2)

    @property
    def profit_loss_percent(self):
        value = ((float(self.total_value) - float(self.total_price))/self.total_value)*100
        return round(value, 1)
```

table I'm adding to below

```html
 {% for transaction in transactions %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{transaction.currency}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.amount_per_coin}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.total_price}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.coin_value}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.total_value}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.date_purchased|date:"j N Y"}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.profit_loss}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.profit_loss_percent}} %</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'transaction-detail' transaction.id %}">View</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network connections to another service are always going to be relatively slow. So what you want to do is find ways to avoid making too many of those requests.

A common method is to cache results for a while. Even a short, few-seconds-range cache can help tremendously if you are processing a lot of transactions that all use a small number of currencies. Right now you make a new request for every property you access, so rendering your table triggers four requests *per transaction row shown*.

Django already has [support for caching data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/); the following would use the cache configured under `CACHES = {..., 'currencies': {...},}` if it exists but otherwise uses the `'default'` configuration. Setting a dedicated cache configuration lets you set things like the timeout for just the currency data.

If you have a Cryptocompare API key, set it in `CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_KEY` in your `settings.py` file:

```
import requests
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import caches, InvalidCacheBackendError

APIURL = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price'

class CurrencyPrices:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()  # re-use connections
        api_key = getattr(settings, 'CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_KEY', None)
        if api_key is not None:
            self.session.headers['Authorization'] = f'Apikey {api_key}'
        try:
            self.cache = caches['currencies']
            self.key_prefix = ''
        except InvalidCacheBackendError:
            self.cache = caches['default']
            self.key_prefix = 'currency_cache_'

    def get_currency_price(self, currency):
        key = f'{self.key_prefix}{currency}'
        value = self.cache.get(key)
        if value is None:
            params = {"fsym": currency, "tsyms": "EUR"}
            response = self.session.get(APIURL, params=params)
            value = response.json()['EUR']
            self.cache.set(key, value)
        return value

_currency_prices = CurrencyPrices()  # single instance per process
get_currency_price = _currency_prices.get_currency_price
```

then import `get_currency_price` and use that to get your values:

```
@property
def coin_value(self):
    return get_currency_price(self.currency)
```

Here is an example cache configuration that caches responses in local memory for 10 seconds:

```
CACHES = {
    'currencies': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'currencies',
        'TIMEOUT': 10,
    }
}
```

Do check what [other settings might be needed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#cache-arguments).